# Here is my proof that the elementary $k$-forms form a basis for $A^k{(\mathbb{R}^n)}$. Is this correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, differential-forms

**Question:**

> Here is my proof that the elementary $k$-forms form a basis for $A^k{(\mathbb{R}^n)}$. Is my proof below correct?

**Context:**

I have searched for an answer in a text book [1]. What I have found is that the authors give a specific proof for the specific case of 2-forms, and then state that "An analogous but *messier* [emphasis added] computation would show that for any $k$-form in and $\mathbb{R}^n$ the form is determined by its values on sequences $\vec{e}_{i,1},\ldots,\vec{e}_{i,k} $..."

This doesn’t meet my needs:

(1) I need to be certain that I understand this proof so that I am confident as I continue my independent study.  Ancillary to this, if the solution for the general case can be written *neatly*, then this augments confidence in the successful comprehension of the definitions, theorems, language, etc. in the remaining material.

(2) I find that the proof of this theorem given in [1] somewhat meanders from the definitional statements; and this too does not meet my needs. I learn most efficiently and effectively when proofs tack more closely to the definitions. So that is what I've attempted to do.

(3) While in their proof the authors of [1] only consider that the arguments of $\varphi$ are given in strictly increasing order. This does not meet my needs.  In my proof I consider the cases where the argument are not necessarily given in strictly increasing order.

**Statement of the Problem:**

Given the following definition

> **Definition ($A^k{(\mathbb{R}^n)}$)** The space of $k$-forms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is denoted
> $A^k{(\mathbb{R}^n)}$,

prove the following theorem.

> **Theorem** (a) The elementary $k$-forms form a basis  for $A^k{(\mathbb{R}^n)}$: every multilinear and antisymmetric function $\varphi$ of $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be uniquely written
> \begin{equation}
> \varphi = \sum_{1\leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n}{a_{i_1\cdots i_k}\,dx_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_k}}.\end{equation}
> (b) The coefficients $a_{i_1, \ldots, i_k}$ are given by $$a_{i_1, \ldots,  i_k} = \varphi{(\vec{e}_{i,1},\ldots,\vec{e}_{i,k})}.$$

**Proof:**

This proof is divided in three parts.  Parts A and B together address part (a) of the theorem; while Part C addresses part (b).

**Part A.** Pursuant to the  definition of linear independence (e.g., cf. [1]), a set of $k$-forms are linearly independent if there is at most one way of writing the multilinear antisymetric function $\varphi$ as a linear combination of $k$-forms; that is, if
$$ \varphi = \sum_{1\leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n}{a_{i_1\cdots i_k}\,dx_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_k}}  = \sum_{1\leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n}{b_{i_1\cdots i_k}\,dx_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_k}}$$
implies
$a_{i_1\cdots i_k} = b_{i_1\cdots i_k}.$

We proceed to   evaluate $\varphi$ on any $k$ standard basis vectors listed in increasing order.
\begin{align}
\varphi{(\vec{e_{j_1}}, \ldots, \vec{e_{j_k}})}
&
 = \sum_{1\leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n}{  {a_{i_1\cdots i_k}\,dx_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_k}}
   } {(\vec{e}_{j_1}, \ldots, \vec{e}_{j_k})}
\\
&
 = \sum_{1\leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n}{  {a_{i_1\cdots i_k} }
   } \det{
   \begin{bmatrix}
   e_{j_1,i_1} & \cdots & e_{j_k,i_k} 
   \\
   \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
   \\
   e_{j_k,i_1}  & \cdots  & e_{j_k,i_k}
   \end{bmatrix} 
   }\quad  \textrm{Eq. 1}
   \\
   &   
   = 
   \begin{cases}
   a_{i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}} & \textrm{for } i_{1} = j_{1}, \ldots, i_{k} = j_{k}   
   \\
   0  & \textrm{otherwise.} 
   \end{cases}  \quad \textrm{Eq. 2}
\end{align}
Similarly, we find
\begin{align}
\varphi{(\vec{e_{j_1}}, \ldots, \vec{e_{j_k}})}
&
   = 
   \begin{cases}
   b_{i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}} & \textrm{for } i_{1} = j_{1}, \ldots, i_{k} = j_{k}   
   \\
   0  & \textrm{otherwise.} 
   \end{cases}
\end{align}
Allowing that $i_{1} = j_{1}, \ldots, i_{k} = j_{k}   $,
\begin{align}
\varphi{(\vec{e_{i_1}}, \ldots, \vec{e_{i_k}})}
& 
  = 
   a_{i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}} \textrm{ and also }
   \\
\varphi{(\vec{e_{i_1}}, \ldots, \vec{e_{i_k}})}
& 
  = 
   b_{i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}}. 
    \end{align}

By the transitive relation [2], whenever $$\varphi{(\vec{e}_{i_1}, \ldots, \vec{e}_{i_k})}
 = a_{i_1, \ldots, i_k} \quad  \textrm{Eq. 3}
$$ and $$\varphi{(\vec{e}_{i_1}, \ldots, \vec{e}_{i_k})}
 = b_{i_1, \ldots, i_k},  
$$ then also $  a_{i_1, \ldots, i_k}   = b_{i_1, \ldots, i_k}  
$. So, we find that the $k$-forms are linearly independent.

**Part B.**
Pursuant to the definition of span (e.g., cf. [1]), the span of the elementary $k$-forms $dx_{i_1}\wedge \cdots\wedge dx_{i_k}$ is the set of linear combinations  $\sum\limits_{1\leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n}{a_{i_1\cdots i_k}  \, dx_{i_1}\wedge \cdots\wedge dx_{i_k} }$.

We ask: Is each and any multilinear and antisymetric function $\varphi$ of $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the span of  $A^k {(\mathbb{R}^n) }$?

We start by proposing that      $$\varphi = \sum\limits_{1\leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n}{a_{i_1\cdots i_k}  \, dx_{i_1}\wedge \cdots\wedge dx_{i_k} }.$$ Following through as done above, we   find that for any standard $k$ basis vectors listed in increasing order
$$\varphi{(\vec{e}_{j_1},\ldots, \vec{e}_{j_k})}
   = 
   a_{j_{1}, \ldots, j_{k}}   .$$
Next we proceed to   evaluate $\varphi$ on any $k$ standard basis vectors -- not necessarily being listed in increasing order. We note from the definition of the determinant of a square matrix $A =[\vec{a}_i, \ldots, \vec{a}_n]$ (e.g., cf. [1]) that exchanging any two arguments changes its sign. Therefore, with respect to Eqs. 1 and 2, we write
\begin{equation}
\varphi{(\vec{e}_{l_1},\ldots, \vec{e}_{l_k})}
   =  (-1)^p\,a_{j_{1}, \ldots, j_{k}},
\end{equation}
where $p$ is a non-negative integer giving the required number of  exchanges of any two of the arguments of $\varphi$ such that  the arguments are ultimately given in   strictly   increasing order. Irrespective of the actual order of the arguments of $\varphi$, we find that $\varphi$ can be written as a linear combination of elementary $k$-forms. So, we find that the $k$-forms span $A^k{(\mathbb{R}^n)}$.

**Part C.** Multiplying both sides of Eq. 3 by -1 and next  adding $(\varphi{(\vec{e}_{i_1}, \ldots, \vec{e}_{i_k})} 
+ a_{i_1, \ldots, i_k})$ to both sides, we find that
$$a_{i_1, \ldots, i_k} = \varphi{(\vec{e}_{i_1}, \ldots, \vec{e}_{i_k})}. $$

*Q.E.D.*

**Bibliography:**

[1] `Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms' by Hubbard and Hubbard, Second Edition, 2002, pp. 193, 195, 469, 562-3.

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would like to point out that Munkres provides an elegant proof in his book Analysis on Manifolds. He first shows a lemma that says: for alternating $k$-tensors $f$ and $g$, if $f(a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_k})=g(a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_k})$ for every ascending $k$-tuple $(i_1,\dots,i_k)$, then $f\equiv g$.

My only criticism is the end of part $B$: compared to the rest of your proof (especially part $C$ - how is that necessary?), your argument for the sign of $\phi$ is almost hand-wavy. I reference Munkres again; he proves basic results (prior to the proof) about permuting the entries of a $k$-tensor, including: if $f$ is alternating and $\sigma$ has odd parity, then $f^\sigma=-f$.

Apart from that (which is just my opinion at the end of the day), I think you have a typo here: "which implies $a_{i_1\cdots i_k} = b_{i_1\cdots i_k}, \ldots, a_k = b_k$."